# Failed to upgrade clusters

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to update image-type and cluster-version of my cluster with `gcloud container clusters upgrade --image-type cos my-cluster --node-pool default-pool --cluster-version=1.7.12-gke.1` but keeps getting this error

> CONTAINER_VM cannot be used with Kubernetes 1.7.6 and above. The
>   CONTAINER_VM image is deprecated and no longer supported. Please
>   choose another image type for this upgrade. See:
>   https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-images

From `kubectl version` it says

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5",
>   GitVersion:"v1.5.3",
>   GitCommit:"029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-02-15T06:40:50Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7+",
>   GitVersion:"v1.7.12-gke.1",
>   GitCommit:"f4f0bedb82a57dc32b21b8f15fe01e0b8411356b",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-05T18:21:59Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Why it does not allow me to upgrade while the error telling me clearly to upgrade?
Or do I have to downgrade kubernetes server to <= 1.7.6? But how to do so?

Comment: Leaving a comment because I haven't done this, but it sounds like you need to create a new node pool for the cluster, e.g. that you cannot change node image type as part of an upgrade.

Comment: It should be possible, the google page above recommends the process from both console and gcloud. When I try from console I got same error. It will be cumbersome if I have to create a new pool.

Comment: Yeah, don't disagree that there is that implication. The upgrade command also suggests as much: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/upgrade. But the container-vm warning makes me think that there is a corner case in here: "Caution: The container-vm node image has been deprecated and is no longer supported as of September 2017. You may no longer create node pools with the container_vm image. You may upgrade existing node pools running container_vm to a maximum Kubernetes version of 1.7.5."

Comment: That is- if you try to just change the image_type without changing anything else, that will probably fail, because you're running a non-supported k8s version. If you try just to upgrade, you can't do that either, bc the min available version is 1.7.12 and container-vm can't run that.

Comment: Yea I'm aware of that, but now I'm kind of stuck with the situation. Maybe you're right, I have to re-create the cluster :(

Comment: I haven't tried this but would guess one can add a node pool, migrate workloads to it, then delete the old pool. Not as bad as making a whole new cluster, shouldn't be any downtime.

Comment: That's a good idea. Will update here once I have tried it. Cheers.